# Detect selected form when Enter key is pressed via jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

We have a web page with 2 forms that contain multiple fields.  The first form has a customer billing address, and the second form has payment information.  When a customer presses the Enter key, the billing address form is always submitted, regardless of whether the field that had focus was in the second payment information form.

The page needs to recognize the user's context, so that if a field in the second form has focus, and that person presses the Enter key, then that second form should submit, instead of the first form.

I am familiar with detecting the keypress event, and have used scripts like this to do so:

```
  detectEnterKey: function () {
      $('body').live('keyup', function (e) {
         if (e.keyCode == 13) {// 'enter' key 
            // Do something
         }
      });
      $('form').keypress(function (e) {
         if (e.which === 13) {
            // Do something
         }
      });
  },
```

What I don't know how to do, is detect the form context to know which form to submit.  I suspect it may be available in the event (function(e)), but haven't seen an example of this.  Thanks.

Comment: `live` is deprecated use `on` - suggesion

Comment: give an id to the form you want to submit.
`$("#myform").submit();`

Comment: But how do I detect which form had focus? That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You find the form that is parent of the field that has the focus when pressing enter and submit it.

```
$('.input').keyup(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 13) {
 $(this).parent().find('.form').submit();
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll give this idea from @almo a shot first.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using JQuery, add JQueryUI and use selectable. It's a very handy tool for what you want.

http://jqueryui.com/selectable/

You can make any DOM element selectable. Also, why use "enter" instead of "del", I think it would make more sense to use the delete key.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the `document.activeElement` to get the focused element. With this you can check wich form has the focus and than only submit that one.
Just check in your code in wich one the activeElement is and only submit that form.